# Python: get currently logged user and his/her special folders

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

Does this code `win32api.GetUserName()` works fine on all win system from win 2000 to win 7 ? 
What about if user is not local user but domain user, does it still work ?

When i use this function `shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_someDirectory, 0, 0)`, do I get wanted folder for currently logged user ?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a module called [getpass](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html) which has a getpass.getuser() function. 
This should work on all windows versions. It did on all the versions I've tried anyway. The user I've used wasn't local either.